# I'm facing a challenge to get a table from a web site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying download from a table with the average incomes from each profession in Brazil from this website:

http://bi.mte.gov.br/bgcaged/caged_perfil_municipio/index.php

I started this task using selenium in Python. However, despite the fact that I use 'time.sleep' to wait the table load, the webdriver can't find the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json



url = 'http://bi.mte.gov.br/bgcaged/caged_perfil_municipio/index.php'


option = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)

driver.get(url)


driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#uf > option:nth-child(2)').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mun > option:nth-child(2)').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#nivel2 > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#TAB4 > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)').click()

time.sleep(10)

try: 
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table')
except: 
    element = driver.find_element_by_css("#dados"")
```

With this script I can select the options, but I can't get the table.

Comment: How are you executing the search?

Comment: The xpath is incorrect. Are you trying to target only the search results? then try targeting specific td/tr with specific ids.

Comment: I were only able to get data from the frame element. If you use element `src` from `<frame noresize="" name="tabela" src="http://bi.mte.gov.br/temp/consulta99511514t.htm">`.

Comment: I tried 
`element = driver.find_element_by_id("dados")`,
 In the website:
 `<table id="dados" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" bordercolorlight="#ffffff" bordercolordark="#D9D6CA" bgcolor="#ffffff">`.

But always it returns: Unable to locate element:

I also have used ChroPath to try get the xpath, but it can't find too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't get the table its because its loaded from an iframe.

To get data from an iframe in selenium use `switch_to` to switch to the iframe

```
time.sleep(2)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_name('iframe1')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#get table url from iframe frame 
table_url=driver.find_element_by_name('tabela').get_attribute("src")
driver.get(table_url)

#test print
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PontoRef"]/th[1]').text)
```

That should print `CBO 2002` the first title in the table you can do the rest for yourself.